# How can i deserialise two xml files with different tags but the same data

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have two xml files with the same data but different tags.  I need to serialise them into an object.  At first i tried to create the classes:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="ONIXMessage")]
public class ONIXMessage
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="release")]
    public string Release { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Header")]
    public Header Header { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Product")]
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }        
}
```

However i'd need to create another class for the xml with different tags.  Unless of course i find a better way to deserialise them.  I currently have something like this:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new
XmlSerializer(type);

FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(fs);

return (ONIXMessage)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Hope i'm making sense.

Comment: Why have you duplicated this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149184/can-i-use-interfaces-or-polymorphism-to-deserialise-two-different-xml-files-into/3149244#3149244

Comment: I didn't think i was asking the correct question.  Your answer in the last thread, however helpful wasn't answering what I thought I had asked.  I assumed it was better to just ask another more direct question than add to the other one. I realised my question was mainly about serialisation not interfaces.. having said that i've just noticed the edit link. So i guess i could have just changed the question.  Ah well, we live and learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [XmlChoiceIdentifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlchoiceidentifierattribute.aspx)?